# The breakpoint will not currently be hit. A copy of file was found in dll file (visual studio community 2019)

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

Solution having a few projects and one of them was library (dll), dll is used in one of the project within same solution,can place breakpoint and debug normally.  After that source code was changed(not totally changed but some functions were updated) and suddenly the breakpoint is not working anymore!

Searched and tried many suggested solutions but none of them fixed the issue.

Comment: What happens if you rebuild the DLL?

Comment: I have rebuild the dll and changed from debug to release and from release to debug but still the same. I cleaned the solution and rebuild again but breakpoint didn't work.

Comment: What happens if you put a breakpoint in your application code and then try to step into the DLL code whilst debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally after two hours of headache.

Posting answer for anyone having similar issue.

1- go to your library  project, and navigate to project folder > obj > debug > .netcoreapp
 then delete library `name.dll`

2- rebuild library project again so

> dll will be generated again according to latest code
>   `This is the trick`

3- rebuild the application again (the application that consume library)

it works great :)